# Get all parent rows that do not have a row for current date in child table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT 
    [dbo].[Mission].[MissionId]  
FROM 
    [dbo].[Mission] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[Report] ON [dbo].[Mission].[MissionId] = [dbo].[Report].[MissionId] 
WHERE 
    [dbo].[Report].ReportDate IS NULL 
ORDER BY 
    [dbo].[Mission].[MissionId]
```

How can I change the above query such that it gives me all `MissionId`'s from table `[dbo].[Mission]` that do not have a row in table `[dbo].[Report]` where `[dbo].[Report].ReportDate` is today?

`MissionId` is the primary key in table `Mission` and a foreign key in table `Report`. So I want to get all missions that do not have a row in table `Report` for the current date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've introduced some aliases to make the query easier to read, and added the needed condition. I've also changed the `WHERE` clause, not sure if that's required:

```
SELECT m.[MissionId]  
FROM [dbo].[Mission] m LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Report] r
  ON m.[MissionId] = r.[MissionId] 
  AND r.ReportDate = DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
WHERE r.MissionId IS NULL 
ORDER BY m.[MissionId]
```

This assumes that `ReportDate` contains dates with the time portions set to midnight. If that's not so, then a slightly more complex query is required:

```
SELECT m.[MissionId]  
FROM [dbo].[Mission] m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from dbo.Report r
                where r.MissionID = m.MissionID and
                   r.ReportDate >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and
                   r.ReportDate < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),1)
                )
ORDER BY m.[MissionId]
```

[`GETDATE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) returns the current date and time. I'm using a couple of tricks with [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms186819%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) and [`DATEDIFF`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) to take that value and turn it into the current date at midnight, and (in the second query) tomorrow's date at midnight.

---

Second query as a fully runnable query:

```
declare @mission table (MissionID int not null);
insert into @mission (MissionID) select 1 union all select 2;
declare @report table (MissionID int not null,ReportDate datetime not null);
insert into @report (MissionID,ReportDate)
select 2,GETDATE() union all select 1,DATEADD(day,-1,GETDATE());

SELECT m.[MissionId]  
FROM @mission m 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(select * from @report r
                where r.MissionID = m.MissionID and
                   r.ReportDate >= DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and
                   r.ReportDate < DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),1)
                )
ORDER BY m.[MissionId]
```

Result:

```
MissionId
-----------
1
```

Comment: on further testing, option 2 does not any rows. Any idea why?

Comment: @SQL.NETWarrior - if you could set up an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with some sample data, or added some sample data to your question and expected results, you'd get fully tested queries. As it is, I can only make up data for which it works. I'm adding a full repro script at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever oh sorry, i was doing one thing wrong. It works.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  m.MissionId
from Mission m 
left join Report r
  on  m.MissionId = r.MissionId
  and day(r.ReportDate) = day(getdate())
  and month(r.ReportDate) = month(getdate())
  and year(r.ReportDate) = year(getdate())
WHERE r.ReportDate is null
ORDER BY m.MissionId
```